# ORA-06502 with varchar2 conversion from clob

Tags: oracle, clob, varchar2, ora-06502

I experimented a little bit with clobs and varchar2. The thing is that we have a lot of XML in a database table and I wanted to download the XML as fast as possible. As I need to use the C# DevArt components I tried it various ways and found out that clobs (they involve one roundtrip to the database per row) are a lot slower than varchar2.

Thus I am right now downloading the data in two steps. First as much as I can as varchar2 (4000 Byte limit) and then everything else as clob.

Now the tricky part. I came up with the following query to find out what I can retrieve as varchar2:

```
 select c.xml.getstringval() from customers c where 
 length(t.xml.getclobval()) = length(dbms_lob.substr(c.xml.getclobval(), 4000, 1))
```

The query is based on the assumption that length is returning the number of characters for clobs and substr is returning the a string with a certain number of bytes. It doesn't work only with length because then I run into trouble with multibytecharacters like à é oder è. But now I have another very strange behaviour. The query above works for most of the rows but for some of them it still throws an ORA-06502. But if I change the limit to 3992 it always works??? (as information, we also store a thumbnail of a picture as Base64 encoded string in the xml).

Does anyone now why the query doesn't work in all cases. Or does anyone have a suggestion how to write a query that find out if a clob can be retrieved as a varchar2?

Answer (score 0):

> substr is returning the a string with a certain number of bytes

The [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_lob.htm#i999349) says that the amount parameter of SUBSTR function means number of characters (not bytes) to be read for CLOBs.

> It doesn't work only with length because then I run into trouble with multibytecharacters like à é oder è

Try using the "[Unicode=true;](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/?Devart.Data.Oracle~Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleConnection~ConnectionString.html)" connection string parameter.

> The query above works for most of the rows but for some of them it still throws an 
>   ORA-06502. But if I change the limit to 3992 it always works???

Please [send us](http://www.devart.com/company/contactform.html) a small test project so that we can reproduce the issue in our environment. Also specify:

- your connection string (roughly, without credentials)
- the DDL/DML script of the corresponding database objects
- the version, NLS_LANGUAGE, NLS_CHARACTERSET, and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET parameters of your Oracle server